# Android Twitter4J set listview data

Tags: android, listview, twitter4j

I'm using `Twitter4J` library to get a user's tweets to set them to a listview. Once the listview updates to set the data, it force closes.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<Status> statuses = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView i = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        final ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxx")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxx")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxxx")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxx");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    try {
        String user;
        user = "xxxxxxx";
        statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);
        Log.i("Status Count", statuses.size() + " Feeds");
        statuses.toArray();
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }

        }
    }).start();

    i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Status>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statuses));

        }
    }
```

the `logcat` is:

```
11-09 12:23:38.488: E/AndroidRuntime(30762): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 12:23:38.488: E/AndroidRuntime(30762): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx/xxxxxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 12:23:38.488: E/AndroidRuntime(30762):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
```

if I remove i.setAdapter, everything is fine and the listview is blank but I get the statuses.size. If i keep it, I get the force close

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the contents of a View from inside a thread. All UI changes must happen on the main UI thread.

So

```
i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Status>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statuses));
```

will raise a `CalledFromWrongThreadException` exception

Comment: sorry for this nobbie question :P please bare me